# Thymeleaf: Check if message with dynamic key is null or empty

Tags: thymeleaf, spring-thymeleaf

the key for the `messages.properties` lookup are provided by my Java Class, as you can see here (where `i` is a variable in a `th:each` loop):

```html
th:text="#{${i.nameKey}}"
```

```java
public String getNameKey() {
    // getKeyPrefix() generates a unique name from the class attributes
    return getKeyPrefix() + ".name";
}
```

This works fine.

Now I want to check if the value in the `messages.properties` file is null or empty for the given key:

```html
th:if="${#messages.msg(i.nameKey) != null AND NOT #string.isEmpty(#messages.msg(i.nameKey))}"
```

But i can't pass the `messages` object into the `isEmpty` method.
Any idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`#messages.msg` does not return null if the key is missing.  From the [docs](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#messages-1):

> If a message is not found, a default message (like '??msgKey??') is returned.

You should use `#messages.msgOrNull` instead.  As for the second part of the question, there is no reason you can't combine `#utility` objects.  That being said, it looks like you have a typo: the utility object `#string` does not exist, but `#strings` does.

```
th:if="${#messages.msgOrNull(i.nameKey) != null AND NOT #strings.isEmpty(#messages.msgOrNull(i.nameKey))}"
```